# Getting Network error when calling Post Api while postman works fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post

I am calling different api from my project with no problem, there is another api from third party running on Amazon and whenever I try to call it, I get network error.

I also tried to call api with different request header settings, different length ( got from postman ) , also remove Content-Length, but none of them worked.

When I call from postman, it works with no issue but I can't call it from my React.js PWA Project.

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

```
  const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": "291",
            Accept: "*/*"
        },

        body = {
           sourceCode: "123",
           targetCode: "567",   
           load: {
             Endpoint: "TRANSACTION",
             cmdType: "GetValue",
             ReqData: {
                Tag: "ABCD"
             }
           }
        }
     };

     fetch(
            "https://dev.ecr.amobilepayment.com:3000/api/command/queue",
            requestOptions
          )
          .then(async (response) => {   
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                const data = await response.json();     
                if (!response.ok) {         
                    const error = (data && data.message) || response.status;
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("ERROR", error);
            });
     console.log("AFTER");
```

It's strange that the console shows only "AFTER" and doesn't show "SUCCESS" and "ERROR" logs. I have used try, catch too, but catch doesn't get exception.

Comment: Use chrome devtools network to see what happened to that fetch?

Comment: Maybe it will give you an idea where the problem is

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the third party had not activated "CORS"  and preflight, in order to accept cross origin calls in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
throw error;
```

instead of

```
return Promise.reject(error);
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said, the Success log which is before that line isn’t hit